# Function return values and rvalue references binding

Tags: c++, c++11, move-semantics

I'm trying to understand move semantics and perfect forwarding in C++
To do this I made next simple program:

```
#include <iostream>

struct Test
{
    Test(){ std::cout << "Test()" << std::endl; }
    Test(Test&&){ std::cout << "Test(Test&&)" << std::endl; }
    Test(const Test&){ std::cout << "Test(const Test&)" << std::endl; }

    ~Test(){ std::cout << "~Test()" << std::endl; }
};

Test MakeTest()
{
    Test t;//output Test()

    return Test(t);//output Test(const Test&)
}//output ~Test

int main()
{
    std::cout << "------------------------------" << std::endl;
    Test t0(MakeTest()); //How is t0 constructed!??
    std::cout << "------------------------------" << std::endl;
    Test t1(std::forward<Test>(MakeTest())); //output Test(Test&&) \n ~Test
    std::cout << "------------------------------" << std::endl;

    return 0;
}//output ~Test \n ~Test
```

The program has following output(VS2013, GCC 4.8 - debug mdoe, optimizations turned off):

```
------------------------------
Test()
Test(const Test&)
~Test()
------------------------------
Test()
Test(const Test&)
~Test()
Test(Test&&)
~Test()
------------------------------
~Test()
~Test()
```

What I don't understand here is how `t0` is constructed. I expected to be constructed using `Test(Test&&)` as return value of `MakeTest()` is unnamed temporary value.

Can you please explain why it does not call any of the 3 constructors I defined?

Comment: The copy/move is probably elided. Search for "return value optimisation" or "copy elision."

Comment: @Angew I disabled all optimizations. I would expect to not use RVO and copy elision here...

Comment: @Felics you provided a command line parameter that said "don't further optimize" - thats not disabling simple things like RVO.

Comment: @Felics Copy ellision is actually part of the language - normally you must tell compilers explicitly not to do it (if they even allow that), simply saying "don't optimise" need not be enough.

Comment: @ArneMertz I know, but how one can understand simple concepts when... they don't work as expected:)

Comment: Try `-fno-elide-constructors`.

Answer (score -1):

@Angew's comment is most probably right, copy/move elision must be charge.

Another point can be that even though Test(t) is temporary, it is still a value, and thus the copy constructor is a closer match.

Anyhow if you want the move constructor to be used for sure, you can use std::move().

```
Test MakeTest()
{
    Test t;
    return std::move(Test(t));
}
```

I used this several times because once we are using move constructors, there could easily be tricks in constructors, we do want to be called.

Comment: Adding the `std::move` prevents elision and can only make the program slower, never faster. Bad idea.